# Links in sidebar to link to search results

Tags: views, navigation, uri

I have a view in sidebar showing a taxonomy `Category`. There is a view on `/search-page` that displays search using Search API view and exposed filters. I want the sidebar Categories to link to the search page with filtered category (`/search-page?filter_category[]=13`)

What would be a proper way of doing this?

I tried to do rewrite on the `Name` field in sidebar view.

- "Rewrite the output of this field"
- rewrite Text to `[name]`
- checked the "Output this field as a link"
- set Link Path to `search-page?field_[machine_name]%5B%5D=[tid]`
- the links in sidebar get double escaped (it's a bug https://www.drupal.org/node/1342124)

In addition to the bug, I don't particularly like this way, because the path is hardcoded.

**Is there a way to kind of link to the search view with some params instead so that Drupal handles the URL internally?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it seems like the double escaping did work OK after all. A rewrote the URL to `search-page?field_[machine_name][]=[tid]` and it worked :)